# Scala generics and type mismatch

Tags: generics, scala

the following code errors with a 'type mismatch' error, saying that FooProcessor should be Processor[M].

```
sealed trait Model
case class Foo extends Model
trait Processor[M <: Model]

class FooProcessor extends Processor[Foo]

class DelegatingProcessor[M <: Model] extends Processor[M] {
  val delegates = Map[String, Processor[M]]("foo" -> new FooProcessor())
}
```

How to you convince the compiler that FooProcessor is an extension of Processor[Model]?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is that your `FooProcessor` is an extension of `Processor[Foo]`, and is specific to `Foo`. In `DelegatingProcessor`, you need a `Processor` that is able to handle not only `Foo`, but any valid `Model`. `FooProcessor` simply doesn't fit the bill here. And — don't try to convince the compiler otherwise, because the compiler is here exactly to prevent this kind of mistakes :-)

Comment: [Scala newbie here]. How many valid Model's are there though? Doesn't 'sealed' mean that Foo is the only one?

Comment: Yes, but the compiler is not allowed to use that information here. If you want to enforce that `Foo` is the only valid model, write `class DelegatingProcessor[M <: Foo]`.